# Объединение строк регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Можно ли написать регулярное выражение, или макрос, чтобы сложить данные строки...? самый обычный для Notepad++

```
Adani & Wolf - Let It Go # Daniel Testas
Adani & Wolf - Let It Go # Rob Gaasterland
Balthazar - True Love # Maarten Devoldere
Balthazar - True Love # Jinte Deprez
Balthazar - True Love # Name 3
```

чтобы получилось вот так:

```
Adani & Wolf - Let It Go # Daniel Testas, Rob Gaasterland  
Balthazar - True Love # Maarten Devoldere, Jinte Deprez, Name 3
```

ну то есть, скалывание информации после решётки, для совпадающей по знакам информации до неё....

Comment: Edit —> Line operations —> Join lines

Comment: @Denis640Kb, вроде это мимо вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повторять замену пока не будет 0:

```
^([^#]*)(#.*)\r?\n\1#(.*)
```

```
$1$2,$3
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ставлю плюсик :)

Comment: Гениально! - Спасибо!!

Comment: Если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Тут не указан ЯП. Надеюсь не это будет ошибкой. Если автор захочет, то решение на php.

```php
$text = '
    Adani & Wolf - Let It Go # Daniel Testas  
    Adani & Wolf - Let It Go # Rob Gaasterland  
    Balthazar - True Love # Maarten Devoldere  
    Balthazar - True Love # Jinte Deprez  
    Balthazar - True Love # Name 3 
';

preg_match_all('/^([^#]+)#([^\n]+)/m', trim($text), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $v) {
    $result[trim($v[1])][] = trim($v[2]);
}

foreach ($result as $k => $v){
    echo $k .' # '. join(', ', $v) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/rYSKA

Comment: 1. Указан NPP. 2. Разве php гарантирует порядок при добавлении в словарь?

Comment: @Qwertiy, 1. вижу, что указан NPP, поэтому сделал решение общим. 2. Не совсем понимаю о чем речь. Приведите пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy, 2. Если речь про разный порядок строк, то вот смотрите: https://3v4l.org/WY1kP

Comment: 1. Я так понимаю, что надо было заменить средствами самого NPP, а не отдельную программу писать. 2. Речь пор то, может ли порядок строк поменяться по сравнению с оригинальным. 3. А вот пример из последнего комментария объединять не факт что просили? Впрочем, скорее всего там такого и нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: А зачем общим сделал? Я убрал, если хочешь, можешь сделать ещё раз.